# How to compile Moses with XMLRPC support?

Tags: xml-rpc, moses

I've installed libxmlrpc-core-c3-dev package (using aptitude) and irstlm in /opt/moses

After that I run

```
./bjam -j4 --with-irstlm=/opt/moses/irstlm --with-xmlrpc-c=/usr/ --prefix=/opt/moses > install.txt
```

Looks like everything is installed successfully exception mosesserver binary. After grepping on install.txt I found out this:

```
gcc.compile.c++ contrib/server/bin/gcc-4.8/release/debug-symbols-on/link-static/threading-multi/mosesserver.o
contrib/server/mosesserver.cpp:16:29: fatal error: xmlrpc-c/base.hpp: No such file or directory
"g++"  -ftemplate-depth-128 -O3 -finline-functions -Wno-inline -Wall -g -pthread -I/usr/include  -DBOOST_SYSTEM_DYN_LINK -DBOOST_THREAD_DYN_DLL -DKENLM_MAX_ORDER=6 -DLM_IRST -DMAX_NUM_FACTORS=4 -DNDEBUG -DTRACE_ENABLE=1 -DWITH_THREADS -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGE_FILES  -I"." -I"moses/TranslationModel/DynSAInclude" -I"util/double-conversion" -c -o "contrib/server/bin/gcc-4.8/release/debug-symbols-on/link-static/threading-multi/mosesserver.o" "contrib/server/mosesserver.cpp"
...failed gcc.compile.c++ contrib/server/bin/gcc-4.8/release/debug-symbols-on/link-static/threading-multi/mosesserver.o...
...skipped <pcontrib/server/bin/gcc-4.8/release/debug-symbols-on/link-static/threading-multi>mosesserver for lack of <pcontrib/server/bin/gcc-4.8/release/debug-symbols-on/link-static/threading-multi>mosesserver.o...
...skipped <p/opt/moses/bin>mosesserver for lack of <pcontrib/server/bin/gcc-4.8/release/debug-symbols-on/link-static/threading-multi>mosesserver.o...
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problem on squeeze.

```
sudo apt-get install libxmlrpc-c3-dev
```

solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to compile libxmlrpc-c manually in /opt/libxmlrpc and set this folder in --with-xmlrpc-c=/opt/libxmlrpc